# How to retrieve interface static IP when the network is down on WINDOWS

Tags: windows, static-ip-address, ipconfig

I have a windows 10 system on which there are 2 NIC's, both connected to different networks and both of them are assigned static IPs (Eg: IP_1=170.30.120.1 and IP_2=10.20.20.1).

When the Network_2 is down momentarily only IP_1 is listed in the commandline when Ipconfig commands were used. Is there a way for me to retrieve both the static IPs even if the network is momentarily down?

I have tried ipconfig , powershell commands and few more. Since the static IPs are assigned to both, can I get both IPs irrespective of their network state?

Answer (score 0):

You can try PowerShell script to get the `NetworkAdapterConfiguration` object and Filter based on DHCPEnabled to be false.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter DHCPEnabled=False -ComputerName . |Format-Table
```

This formats the output in a table format. However, you can play around with the command a bit more to get the desired output format and information by changing Filter etc.

Comment: Thank you. The above PS command to use NetworkAdapterConfiguration object did not display the static IP address whose status is "Network cable unplugged" in adaptor settings. I tired few other NetworkAdapterConfiguration  ps command options too, but it is not returning that static IP.

Comment: I stumbled upon another PowerShell command **"Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | select ipaddress"**  which gives us the list of all IPV4 IPs in the system with their respective state.